# What's the relationship between lexical change and word-formation?

Tags: morphology, lexical-semantics

Do both the lexical change(invention, blending, abbreviation, acronym, etc) and derivation belong to word-formation?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "word-formation". If you mean "where do words come from?" then the answer is yes. If you mean something like "what are the rules describing permissible words?" then the answer is probably no.

Comment: Thank you. But I am still confused that why we often refer Derivational Morphology to Word-formation?